Email threading when sending emails from an Account record
I have set up email to case and threading that allows us to see the history of the conversation on the Case record.
I have a requirement where the client would like to be able to send out an email from activities section on an Account record and capture the returning reply on the call log, etc.
Does email threading work in such circumstances, or is it just for the Case record?
Thanks.

They used to be just for Cases, but new thread tokens can be used with other objects, too. However, you will have to write your own Apex Email Service if you want the threading to work for objects other than Case:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_threadingtokens_platform.htm&release=250&type=5
(I haven't used thread tokens with objects other than Case before, so I can't confirm how well it works.)
Creating email services: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_email_services.htm&type=5

thanks for your reply. It was very helpful.
